# VAULT_CLIENT_TOKEN keeps expiring every 24h

Tags: concourse, hashicorp-vault

Environment:

Vault + Consul, all latest. Integrating Concourse (3.14.0) with Vault. All tokens and keys are throw-away. This is just a test cluster.

Problem:

No matter what I do, I get `768h` as the `token_duration`  value. Also, overnight my approle token keeps expiring no matter what I do. I have to regenerate token and pass it to Concourse and restart the service. I want this token not to expire.

```
[root@k1 etc]#  vault write auth/approle/login role_id="34b73748-7e77-f6ec-c5fd-90c24a5a98f3" secret_id="80cc55f1-bb8b-e96c-78b0-fe61b243832d" duration=0
Key                     Value
---                     -----
token                   9a6900b7-062d-753f-131c-a2ac7eb040f1
token_accessor          171aeb1c-d2ce-0261-e20f-8ed6950d1d2a
token_duration          768h
token_renewable         true
token_policies          ["concourse" "default"]
identity_policies       []
policies                ["concourse" "default"]
token_meta_role_name    concourse
[root@k1 etc]#
```

So, I use token - `9a6900b7-062d-753f-131c-a2ac7eb040f1` for my Concourse to access secrets and all is good, until 24h later. It gets expired.

I set duration to 0, but It didn't help.

```
$ vault write auth/approle/role/concourse secret_id_ttl=0 period=0 policies=concourse secret_id_num_uses=0 token_num_uses=0
```

My modified `vaultconfig.hcl` looks like this:

```
storage "consul" {
  address = "127.0.0.1:8500"
  path    = "vault/"
  token = "95FBC040-C484-4D16-B489-AA732DB6ADF1"
  #token = "0b4bc7c7-7eb0-4060-4811-5f9a7185aa6f"
}

listener "tcp" {
  address     = "0.0.0.0:8200"
  cluster_address = "0.0.0.0:8201"
  tls_min_version = "tls10"
  tls_disable = 1
}

cluster_addr = "http://192.168.163.132:8201"
api_addr = "http://192.168.163.132:8200"
disable_mlock = true
disable_cache = true
ui = true
default_lease_ttl = 0
cluster_name = "testcluster"
raw_storage_endpoint = true
```

My Concourse policy is vanilla:

```
[root@k1 etc]# vault policy read concourse
path "concourse/*" {
  policy = "read"
  capabilities =  ["read", "list"]
}
[root@k1 etc]#
```

Look up token - `9a6900b7-062d-753f-131c-a2ac7eb040f1`

```
[root@k1 etc]# vault token lookup 9a6900b7-062d-753f-131c-a2ac7eb040f1
Key                  Value
---                  -----
accessor             171aeb1c-d2ce-0261-e20f-8ed6950d1d2a
creation_time        1532521379
creation_ttl         2764800
display_name         approle
entity_id            11a0d4ac-10aa-0d62-2385-9e8071fc4185
expire_time          2018-08-26T07:22:59.764692652-05:00
explicit_max_ttl     0
id                   9a6900b7-062d-753f-131c-a2ac7eb040f1
issue_time           2018-07-25T07:22:59.238050234-05:00
last_renewal         2018-07-25T07:24:44.764692842-05:00
last_renewal_time    1532521484
meta                 map[role_name:concourse]
num_uses             0
orphan               true
path                 auth/approle/login
policies             [concourse default]
renewable            true
ttl                  2763645
[root@k1 etc]#
```

Any pointers, feedback is very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `token_ttl` and `token_max_ttl` parameters instead of the `secret_id_ttl` when creating the new AppRole.

You should also check your Vault `default_lease_ttl` and `max_lease_ttl`, they might be set to 24h

Comment: Thanks for replying @gic186. Tried `vault mount-tune` to change and re-generated token for approle. `vault mount-tune --max-lease-ttl=0 -default-lease-ttl=0 /concourse`. Re-generated token.  Still shows 768h as for `token_duration`.

Comment: Tried with `vault auth tune` command and regenerated token. Still shows `768h`. Grrrrrr!!!

Comment: My bad, I misunderstood your question. 768h is the default value for the ttl, and i don't remember if  setting it to 0 means default or infinite. Have you tried setting the token_ttl?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @gic186. Since I am using `approle`, I wonder if setting `token_ttl` will even have an impact. I can try though.. Thanks again for your reply!

Comment: Well, it is in the AppRole documentation https://www.vaultproject.io/api/auth/approle/index.html#token_ttl

Comment: Thanks so much @gic186. Will do it next and keep you posted!!

Comment: Narrator: He did not keep us posted